# How would you animate this surgical thread?

Tags: animation, workflow

I need to make an animation of a surgical thread similar to this one and I'm wondering what would be the best way to do it?

[image]

Right now the best workflow I thought was:

-Adding a middle shape that act as a collision object with a transparent material, and add a very stiff cloth cilinder controlled with a empty hook. Then skin would be animated with some bones.

I want to know if you know a better or more efficient way to do this!

Thanks!

Comment: with the curve's handles hooked to bones?